# shared Shader Locations for different shaders

Tags: opengl

I have two shaders with different in's:

```
in vert;
```

and

```
in vert;
in text;
```

Will I get the same location from both shaders when I call `glGetAttribLocation(program, "vert")`?
So can I use the first shader whenever I can use the second shader?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you do not explicitely assign the attribute locations, the GL will use an arbitrary mapping. (I've seen alphabetical ordering on at least one implementation, but the spec does not guarantee anything).

If you want reliable attribute locations, you can explicitely specify them. Use either [`glBindAttribLocation`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glBindAttribLocation.xml) (which has to be done before linking, as the attribute locations are determined at link time), or specify the locations directly in the shader source ([`GL_ARB_explicit_attrib_location`)](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/explicit_attrib_location.txt) via the [`layout(location=...)`](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Layout_Qualifier_%28GLSL%29#Interface_layouts) qualifiers when declaring the inputs. The latter path is available since GLSL 3.30.